# Java and javac not working in cmd. Both java and javac "is not recognized as an internal.."

Tags: java, compiler-errors, path, javac, system-variable

I am having som trouble with java, i have tried to fix my Path, but i am new to programming and don`t know what to do.

I have java installed at : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin`

and at : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin`

Here are some screenshots from my system variables: This pops up when i click on the system variable "Path", see the other picture.

[image]

System variables

[image]

When I am in cmd, and writing `java -version` or `javac -version`, I get this message:

> "java/javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Have tried to restart cmd every time i have changed the path.

Comment: windows (used to, not sure where it stays now) need restart of command prompt. can you check by restarting command prompt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Setting separate variables for JDK & JRE

Also give a backslash "\" after bin in the case of both JDK & JRE

Hope this works

Comment: How do i do this? Sorry, I am new into this.

Answer (score 0):

**First go to this path to make sure that it is right.
second try to restart your cmd and try again.**

Comment: And what is the right path for me? Can you see that from my pictures?

Comment: I mean try to navigate to this path.

Comment: navigate where? I have navigated to bin in my java folder (see my question).

Comment: remove -> ( " ) symbol in the first of path , and try again.

Comment: if it doesno't work , try to remove it and go to the oracle path "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" and make sure that java.exe , javaw.exe and javaws.exe are existing in this path , then try java -version from your cmd again (without adding bin path of java).